# C# replacing a string

Tags: c#, replace, uppercase, lowercase

I have one list with words and their replacing words, for example:

desk-->table
etc.

So lets say if user write **desk** it will give result **table** but if user write **Desk** with capital **D** it will not do any change. I know how to ignore uppercase but then the world will be replaced with **table** where **t** is lowercase... I want the **t** to be uppercase. So if desk-->table and if Desk-->Table... How i can do that?

Comment: Have you had a look into RegEx ?

Comment: No i havent... So you mean RegEx will solve my problem, right?

Comment: You could do a second call to the replace function, and replace Desk with Table, instead of ignoring the casing. I have a question though, if the original word is DEsk, should it be replaced with TAble? Or this applies to the first letter only?

Comment: @Tibi only to the first element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the replace function a second time, the second time with the capital words.

For example:

```
string result = input.Replace ("desk", "table");
result = result.Replace ("Desk", "Table");
```

To get the first character of a string to uppercase is not very difficult. You could use this method:

```
string lower = "desk";
string upper = char.ToUpper(lower[0]) + lower.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you have a list with words and their replacing words. So the data structure will be

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("desk","table");
dict.Add("Desk","Table");
```

If this is correct, then the following will work

```
var result = dict["Desk"];
```

But if you are maintaining the values in the below way,

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("desk","table");
```

then the solution may be

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("desk","table");


        string input = "Desk";
        var dictValue = dict[input.ToLower()];
        var result = IsInitCap(input.Substring(0, 1)) 
                     ? System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dictValue)
                     : dictValue;                

    }

    private bool IsInitCap(string str)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^[A-Z]");
        return match.Success ? true : false;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to make the first letter of the input string to UpperCase,

```
str = str.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", str.Skip(1));
```

Now in your case, use the Dictionary data structure to store data.

1. Store the input value as such (key)desk->table(value)
2. Now use the above code and make the first letter uppercase and store it (Desk->Table)

So you can now get the values as if desk-->table and if Desk-->Table.

This always fetches the value in time complexity O(1) by compromising the space complexity.